# Does "well" with "at least" used in the following sentence sound natural?

Tags: grammar

Well, they are consistent at least.

Does this sound natural?

Comment: It sounds fine. I would go with "Well, at least they are consistent" if you are trying to put emphasis on the fact that a lot of things are wrong, but they are still consistent.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. How about "Well, at least they are consistent with something".

Comment: You could even say "Well, they are at least consistent."  In any order, you'd probably stress the end of the sentence when speaking it.  So your version stresses "least" (meaning you're emphasizing that they are doing the least possible thing), whereas the versions that @TreFox and I mention stress "consistent" (meaning that their consistency is important or remarkable).

Comment: Thanks very much. That's very informative. I wanted to emphasise that "they" usually change their stance or stand on almost every issue, but, in this case they haven't. Does this sentence make that clear? "Well, at least they are consistent with something."

Comment: Yes, that's very clear.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to emphasis being consistent is.

If they usually change their stance and this time they have not, then this time they are being inconsistent. You might say

> Usually, they consistently change their mind, but not this time.

Which means they usually are indecisive, constantly changing their mind, but this time they made a decision and did not change it.

However, if you mean the opposite, that they don't usually change their mind, but this time they have first saying "yes", then "no", then you might say

> Usually, they stay consistent *(with their first decision)*, but not this time.

Answer (score 0):

I think **well** is just a discourse marker which makes a conversation natural.It is nothing to do with the usage **atleast** which refers back to consistent.

Comment: "at least" is two words, not one.